# Inner Shadow in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

What is the IE 7+ compatible CSS code for the following:

```
 -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably will have to use an IE filter: [Shadow Filter for IE 5.5+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Or this other approach, but I'm not sure about the inset part: [Box Shadow - CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/)

Answer (score 0):

IE7/8 does not support `box-shadow` in standard CSS.

It is possible to get it working using IE's proprietary `filter` style, but this can be pretty painful and definitely non-standard.

An alternative is to use [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/). This is a small javascript hack for IE 6/7/8 that implements the standard CSS `box-shadow`, and a few other styles into these old browsers.

Simply download the css3pie script `pie.htc` and copy it to your site. Then reference it in your CSS alongside the `box-shadow` style:

```
.myClass {
  -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
}
```

See the CSS3Pie website for more: http://css3pie.com/

Comment: Note that PIE.htc currently does not support "inset" box-shadows.

Answer (score 0):

Read my article:
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/cross-browser-box-shadows/

In case of solid background it is real to create inset box-shadow in IE8-.